# Не получается сделать запрос поля с временем в postgresql из foreign table mssql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-server

В PostgreSQL подключена таблица MSSQL через  foreign table

```
SELECT "CONTACT_ID", 
TO_TIMESTAMP("CREATED", 'Mon DD YYYY HH:MI:SS:USAM') AS "CREATED" 
FROM mssql."CONTACT"
```

выходит

> invalid input syntax for type timestamp : "Dec 25 2015 09:07:47:0000000AM

Comment: Гм... а если брать напрямую значение из поля как строковый литерал - вернётся именно показанная строка?

Comment: В смысле попробовать что-то типа `.. TO_TIMESTAMP("CREATED" :: VARCHAR, 'Mon DD YYYY HH:MI:SS:USAM') AS "CREATED" ..`

Comment: Пробовал так пишет ошибка синтаксиса, попробовал  CAST("CREATED" AS VARCHAR)  b TO_CHAR("CREATED", 'Mon DD YYYY HH:MI:SS:USAM')  так же не выводит.

Comment: Покажите, что выдаст, если спросить ``SELECT "CONTACT_ID", "CREATED" AS "CREATED" 
FROM mssql."CONTACT"``

Comment: какой именно сторонний fdw используете? Как создана foreign table, какого типа данных поле CREATED? какого типа данных это поле на источнике?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, формат времени в `TO_TIMESTAMP` не соответствует формату времени в  `CREATED`. Указанный формат времени соответствует такому виду: `Dec 25 2015 09:07:47:0000000AM`.
По моей практике, чаще всего применяется такой формат времени: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS`.
Тогда код скрипта будет выглядеть так:

```
SELECT "CONTACT_ID", 
       TO_TIMESTAMP("CREATED", 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') AS "CREATED" 
FROM mssql."CONTACT"
```

Скопируйте и вставьте в комментарий пример строки `CREATED` из базы данных. Я подберу нужный формат.